# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. what is wrong

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel

I have been replicating same thing from youtube tutorial for my application, it work there but i got error.
data does console log in the terminal but i am unable to render in Next js component.

i am using postgresQl in vercel and i am able to seed the data properly but unable to render it.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getEducation() {
  const edu = await prisma.education.findMany();
  return edu;
}

const dbtest = async () => {
  const edus = await getEducation();
console.log(edus);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      {edus.map((edu) => (
        <div key={edu.id}>{edu.board}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default dbtest;
```

while running http://localhost:3000/dbtest,

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I have search all the details

what am i doing wrongh here??
my Data that is being fetched is

```js
[
  {
    id: 7627,
    year: 2016,
    institution: 'Hillsdale University',
    degree: 'reprehenderit vitae corporis',
    percentage: '86%',
    board: 'est sed',
    createdAt: '2019-07-30T02:36:26.287Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2548,
    year: 2007,
    institution: 'Leuschke, Schiller and Fadel',
    degree: 'recusandae totam officiis',
    percentage: '66%',
    board: 'quia explicabo',
    createdAt: '2015-06-13T10:20:33.480Z'
  },
  {
    id: 7649,
    year: 2018,
    institution: 'Morar, Gutkowski and Kshlerin',
    degree: 'ratione repudiandae rerum',
    percentage: '92%',
    board: 'enim quibusdam',
    createdAt: '2021-08-05T23:11:47.874Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4382,
    year: 2012,
    institution: 'Gleason - Gutmann',
    degree: 'voluptatum inventore sapiente',
    percentage: '59%',
    board: 'dolorem totam',
    createdAt: '2017-02-18T15:44:21.751Z'
  },
  {
    id: 9821,
    year: 2005,
    institution: 'Fay, Braun and Kozey',
    degree: 'voluptatem est quia',
    percentage: '71%',
    board: 'in dignissimos',
    createdAt: '2013-11-27T00:51:02.840Z'
  }
]
```

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

using this is also not working

Comment: Looks like an issue with how you're fetching your data. dbtest is a React component and it can't be an async function - also look for naming conventions for components. You have to run the fetch in a `useEffect` - see the docs [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects). Your code looks a bit like Server Components but if you're rendering it client side, you'll get your mentioned error. The docs for Prisma server components are [here](https://www.prisma.io/react-server-components#react-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't support rendering JSX directly from asynchronous functions. You should use `useEffect` and `useState` to handle the asynchronous operation.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

function dbtest() {
  const [educationData, setEducationData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const edu = await prisma.education.findMany();
        setEducationData(edu);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      {educationData.map((edu) => (
        <div key={edu.id}>{edu.board}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DbTest;
```